# Why do Visual C++ and g++ give different output for my program?

Tags: c++

I have written a C++ code and faced two

First, when I compile the following code with two different compilers (Visual C++ and g++), they create different outputs for `H[][]` matrix.

The VC++ results are correct and the result of H matrix produced by g++ are wrong. I use `g++ -O -o output myfile.cpp` in cygwin.

I checked my code line by line but I couldn't find reason.

Second, when I assign a large number for `x` and `t` arrays (e.g. 30), my code meets an Error.

Comment: You probably have a bug. Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 7):

Global variables such as:

```
int n, m, beta;
```

are initialized to zero. And then, you allocate memory using their values:

```
char *t = new char[n];
char *x = new char[m];
```

Later you read `n` and `m` but assume that `t` and `x` can be accessed as if their sizes correspond to the new values of `n` and `m`. You most likely end up accessing memory out of range.

That is undefined behavior.

What you need is initialize `t` and `x` to `nullptr` and allocate memory for them in `main`

```
char *t = nullptr;
char *x = nullptr;

int main()
{
    cout << "Enter n (size of t);" << endl;
    cin >> n;

    cout << "Enter m (size of x):" << endl;
    cin >> m;

    // Allocate memory for t and x.
    t = new char[n];
    x = new char[m];
```

Comment: Same goes for G and H.

Comment: tnx R Sahu.You solved my first problem and both VC++ and g++ creates the same output. But when I assign a big value (e.g. 50) to t and x, VC++ reports some Exceptions such as "Access violation reading location..." and cannot create exe file. and g++ create output but gives the following exception:

Comment: tnx R Sahu.You solved my first problem and both VC++ and g++ creates the same output. But when I assign a big value (e.g. 50) to t and x, VC++ reports some Exceptions such as "Access violation reading location..." and cannot create exe file. and g++ create output but gives the following exception:"cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to output.exe.stackdump

Comment: @alijanavar Did you fix G and H also?

Comment: g++ reports **scope error** for :" char *t = nullptr" and "char *x = nullptr".

Comment: error:nullptr was not declared in this scope  char *t = nullptr

Comment: @alijanavar I recommend opening new questions with your new questions. Not only is moving the goalposts for a question frowned on, it has destructive effects on the coherence of answers. A sprawling question and answer degrades the use of the answer to a future individual with a similar problem.

Comment: @alijanavar, `nullptr` is not a valid value to use unless you use C++11 or higher. You can use `-std=c++11` as a command line option to be able to use `nullptr`.